# formsauthentication - loginurl

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I am not sure what the event is called but I'm trying to get it so if your not logged in you can't manually type the page name in the bar at the top. I need to find a way so it will always redirect you to the login page if you haven't signed in.

Also the same goes for sessions, at the moment when my session time runs out my website fails as there is alot linked to sessions from my database, how do I get it so when a session expires upon trying to navigate inside the website you are passed back to the login page?

Comment: You can set this up in the web.config to happen automatically via `loginurl `.

Comment: Please rename the topic of this question into something that is more specific.

Comment: if I knew what it was called I would erno

Comment: Did the edit for you. Hope that's ok :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a good resource for formsauthentication:
http://geekswithblogs.net/AaronLi/archive/2007/02/20/106761.aspx

Comment: Happy to help. It took me some time to get my head around formsauthentication too :)

Answer (score 0):

To your first question, it's not an event, but [Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t6b43z4.aspx) will implement the behaviour you require.

As to your second, configure your session timeout to be the same value as the forms authentication cookie.